# Bulk Import JSON documents into MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I have a directory with 18K json documents. I'm trying to do a bulk import into MongoDB. I wrote this script in Python to load everything in. This code gives me a syntax error since it doesn't seem that Pymongo has 'mongoimport' function. How would I correct this code so that I could do a bulk import of json files from a directory.

```
import json 
import glob 
from pymongo import MongoClient 

directory = '/home/mongo/data/*.json' 
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017) 
db = client.nba 
collection = db.test
jsonFiles = glob.glob(directory) 

for file in jsonFiles: 
    mongoimport --db nba --collection sigOptBox --file file
```

Answer (score 0):

`mongoimport` is a standalone executable. Assuming it is your search path, you can use `call` from the `subprocess` module to call it:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import call
args = shlex.split("mongoimport --db nba --collection sigOptBox --file file")
call(args)
```